# Refresh Fragment view when RecyclerView.Adapter is changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am following Shrine example application which is implemented in Kotlin part of Google official codelabs for developers. [The application](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-codelabs) and [codelab](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-104-kotlin#6)

The last step, We are asked to

> Modify your Shrine application to change the product images shown when
> a category is selected from the backdrop menu.

In the `ProductGridFragment#onCreateView` I attached a onClick listener on one button to begin with (list of categories, are buttons).

As a test, I just popped an element from the list firstly used in Adapter.

```
theList = ProductEntry.initProductEntryList(resources)
adapter = StaggeredProductCardRecyclerViewAdapter( theList )

val featured = view.findViewById(R.id.featured) as Button
// set on-click listener
featured.setOnClickListener {
        theList.pop(1)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

It is not working. Is there other things to do to refresh the view ? all I see in `onCreateView` seems to be just for first creation of the fragment, I mean, when `onClick` is produced, it seems to me sufficient to just modify the list and notify adapter on changes.

Do I have to do any thing with `view` object ?

Any hints ?

Edit 1:

I assigned a new adapter and it works now, this is very nice; Although I do not feel it is performance efficient, as notify for data changes is not really used as intended

```
featured.setOnClickListener {
    theList = ProductEntry.initProductEntryList(resources, "featured")
    this.adapter = StaggeredProductCardRecyclerViewAdapter(
            theList )
    view.recycler_view.adapter = this.adapter
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Java/Kotlin you always pass by value, not a reference. So when you passed the list to the `StaggeredProductCardRecyclerViewAdapter( theList )`, you should update the list from Adapter, not the one you passed, so for example:

```kotlin
class StaggeredProductCardRecyclerViewAdapter(private val theList: List) {

    private var listOfItems = theList

    fun removeItem(position: Int) {
        listOfItems = listOfItems.remove(position)
        notifyDatasetChanged()
    }
}

val featured = view.findViewById(R.id.featured) as Button
// set on-click listener
featured.setOnClickListener {
       adapter.removeItem(1)
}
```

EDIT:

I went to the codebase and you are operating on the immutable list inside the `StaggeredProductCardRecyclerViewAdapter`. If you want to filter the items on the list based on "featured" for example, you should do this:

```kotlin
class StaggeredProductCardRecyclerViewAdapter(private val initList: List<ProductEntry>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredProductCardViewHolder>() {

    private var productList: List<ProductEntry>? = initList

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position % 3
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StaggeredProductCardViewHolder {
        var layoutId = R.layout.shr_staggered_product_card_first
        if (viewType == 1) {
            layoutId = R.layout.shr_staggered_product_card_second
        } else if (viewType == 2) {
            layoutId = R.layout.shr_staggered_product_card_third
        }

        val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
        return StaggeredProductCardViewHolder(layoutView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StaggeredProductCardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (productList != null && position < productList.size) {
            val product = productList[position]
            holder.productTitle.text = product.title
            holder.productPrice.text = product.price
            ImageRequester.setImageFromUrl(holder.productImage, product.url)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList?.size ?: 0
    }

    fun replaceList(items: List<ProductEntry>?) {
        productList = items
        notifyDatasetChanged()
    }
}
```

And in ProductGridFragment:

```kotlin
...
featured.setOnClickListener {
       adapter.replaceList(ProductEntry.initProductEntryList(resources, "featured"))
}
```

Comment: there is no differences update the list from adapter or not.

Comment: yes, I already updated the list outside the adapter in another work, but in case of listView not recyclerView I assume it is the same. Java pass references by value ! I have a deep knowledge on these internals. thanks Mariusz anyway.

Comment: @i30mb1 There is a difference and it's fundamental way of how the Java/Kotlin works

Comment: @Curcuma_ I checked the project and the code I posted should work and should show you how to change the items with RecyclerView

Comment: I am giving it a try, much cleaner approach, I am trying it

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't refresh the view, I am frustrated as I cannot move this forward,

Comment: my bad, meanwhile when I followed your code I had an error initializing my list, this works 100% ! Bravo

Comment: Great :) Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to run again onCreateView with out creating a new instance of the fragment you can just use this:

```
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(yourFragment).commitNow()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(yourFragment).commitNow()
```

This will rerender the whole view.

Based on different cases maybe you need to use childFragmentManager

But the right and most efficient solution when adapter data changes is to use         notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: I saw this, but just assigning a new adapter instantiated with another list already works (see my edit 1). So I prefer not to refresh the view this way, as you can see, I am looking how to make `notifyDatasetChanged` work (just changing the list and nothing else, as intended), because it doesn't and I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

The Simple Way to refresh RecyclerView in fragment add this code:

```
viewpager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
```

it will call `onResume()` methode of the fragment

Work 100%